# How can I reuse a Thymeleaf template in a Java servlet project (without Spring)

Tags: java, thymeleaf

How can I reuse a Thymeleaf template in a Java servlet project (without 
Spring)?

I need to change the fragment depending the path mapped.

The method `doGet` of the servlet is:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    WebContext wContext = new WebContext(request, response, request.getServletContext(), request.getLocale());
    ITemplateEngine template = ThymeleafAppUtlil.getTemplateEngine(request.getServletContext());
    template.process("GenericTemplate", wContext,response.getWriter()); 
}
```

The class  ThymeleafAppUtlil is:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

public class ThymeleafAppUtlil {
    private ThymeleafAppUtlil() {
        super();
    }
public static TemplateEngine getTemplateEngine(ServletContext context) {
        TemplateEngine templateEngine;
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(context);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/thymeleaf/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCacheTTLMs(0L);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return templateEngine;
    }
}
```

The version of thymeleaft used is:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
       <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
       <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I read about the documentation but still not found a solution. Can anyone give me some tips for helping me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

to use static field:

```java
@WebListener
public class ThymeleafListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public static TemplateEngine engine;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        engine = ThymeleafUtil.getTemplateEngine(sce.getServletContext());
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```